# KoalaWriter - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, segmentation-fault

I just downloaded the tar.gz file for the "KoalaWriter", a word editor that helps focus on the writing. In the Terminal I went to the folder "KoalaWriter" in my home directory, then did exactly what was described in the Readme.txt. After that the program doesn't run with the error "segmentation fault (core dumped)". What could be wrong and how could it be fixed? Am using Kubuntu 12.04.

I read general posts about segmentation faults, but it seems to depend on each software's case. Any experience with KoalaWriter?

Install Instructions of the Readme.txt:

To compile this application you need the Qt4 library, you can find it here: http://qt.nokia.com. You need the phonon module for the audio.

On a Debian or derivates systems (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Linux Mint ecc.) you can install dependecies by typing:
*sudo apt-get install build-essential qt4-dev-tools libphonon-dev*

To Compile type:
*qmake*

and then:
*make*

To run type:
*./KoalaWriter*

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with an earlier version of the program the issue is solved. There seems to have been a general problem in Kubuntu 12.04 with version 1.0.1 of the KoalaWriter. See https://code.google.com/p/koalawriter/issues/detail?id=6

Now, I just downloaded the other version 1.0.0, did the installation as described in the README.txt and it works just fine. Using "sudo" before the commands is not necessary.

Thanks.